# "Use of unresolved identifier" when archiving the app

Tags: ios, swift, compilation, swiftui, appdelegate

I have a custom Swift class in the Xcode project, let's name it `CustomClass` When archiving, I get the following error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'CustomClass'

in every file I call that class. Since this class simply creates a `UIViewController`, I've replaced the output of the method invocation with `UIViewController()` call.

Then, I get the following error during the archive:

> Entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64

I've checked my AppDelegate file and found the class definition to be correct:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Since the `@UIApplicationMain` declaration is present, there should be an entry point.

What could be the root cause for this issue?

**Xcode 11.2.1 GM Seed**

Note, the problem happens only when archiving, not creating a debug build. I'm also able to install the app on my device.

Comment: Is your CustomClass declaration file available to all necessary targets?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Double-checked

Answer (score 0):

Check the file's target membership.Select the file and then at one corner (File Inspector Section) at the bottom you can see the target membership.

Comment: Target membership is selected as it should be. A single target and it's "On"